# when insert length of lob data to be replicated exceeds configured maximum 65536

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, replication

I am trying to insert a value into a column of datatype image in SQL Server. I am getting the following error:

```
Length of LOB data (70823) to be replicated exceeds configured maximum 65536.  
The statement has been terminated.
```

The data length is less than 2 MB.

What is the problem?

Comment: I am getting this error in asp.net application.

Comment: you should mark the answer that has helped you as correct

Answer (score 19):

For SQL Server 2005 or earlier you can run:

```
sp_configure 'max text repl size', 2147483647
```

For SQL Server 2008 or later you can run:

```
sp_configure 'max text repl size', -1
```

The former increases the maximum size allowed, the latter essentially says "remove the limit". Once the maximum size is increased or removed, large LOBs will be able to be replicated.

Comment: Do you happen to know how to fix the same problem when it occurs for columns of type VARBINARY(MAX)? (They're also FILESTREAM if that matters).

Comment: How come you do not recommend setting the size option to -1 or no maximum?

Comment: @Nat it looks like -1 only became available as of SQL 2008 (see Brian's comment here: http://sqlmusings.wordpress.com/2008/09/22/issue-length-of-lob-data-to-be-replicated-exceeds-configured-maximum-65536/)

Comment: Amended my answer to add the -1 case.

Comment: What if you don't want to change the size though, how do you find the table and column causing the issue?

Answer (score 5):

Don't forget to run `RECONFIGURE` after running  `sp_configure` so that your changes can take effect

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you can configure the max text replication size option via SQL Server Management Studio

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179573.aspx

> **To configure the max text repl size option**
>   1. In Object Explorer, right-click a server and select Properties.
>   2. Click the Advanced node.
>   3. Under Miscellaneous, change the Max Text Replication Size option to the desired value.

I've tested it in SQL Server 2012, but from the previous link you can view the instructions for 2005 and 2008 which are the same.