# Length of LOB data (78862) to be replicated exceeds configured maximum 65536

Tags: sql-server-2008, replication, database-replication

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925824/when-insert-length-of-lob-data-to-be-replicated-exceeds-configured-maximum-65536) is a related question.

Why do I get this error even when I have not installed SQL Server replication ? The strangest thing is, when I run the fix

```
sp_configure 'max text repl size', 2147483647
Go
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

it works and I no longer get this error

Comment: I've suggested CDC as one possible answer. If it's not that, it might be worth listing anything that's been switched on on your server instance that isn't on by default on SQL Server - e.g. Mirroring, snapshot isolation, etc, and anything other than the database instance - e.g. integration services, analysis services, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [when insert length of lob data to be replicated exceeds configured maximum 65536](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/925824/when-insert-length-of-lob-data-to-be-replicated-exceeds-configured-maximum-65536)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Are you using Change Data Capture?

From [How to: Configure the max text repl size Option (SQL Server Management Studio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179573.aspx)

> This option applies to transactional replication and Change Data Capture

Answer (score 15):

The following steps should be performed:

1. Go to SQL Server management Studio
2. Right-click a server and select Properties
3. Select Properties
4. Go to advanced page
5. Change the max text replication size to any value you want

Answer (score 1):

Go to Management Studio then follow below steps

Right-clicking the server -> Properties -> Advanced tab -> Miscellaneous -> Change Max Text Replication Size to (-1) -> Click OK