# Length of LOB data to be replicated exceeds configured maximum

Tags: sql-server, size, read-eval-print-loop, lob

I'm getting the error shown in the screenshot when I try to insert a text with length 90166 in the production database. The issue is that I'm only getting this error from a specific database in the production database. When I run the same insert with the same length of text in another database, it trims the additional text and makes its length to 65536. There are many resources that say we can update 'max text repl size' to -1 and get rid of this issue. But I'm trying to figure out how the text gets trimmed in one database and why this error pops up in another.

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Length of LOB data (78862) to be replicated exceeds configured maximum 65536](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441081/length-of-lob-data-78862-to-be-replicated-exceeds-configured-maximum-65536)